# How to solve margin problem between two components inside a Modal in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react-native project inside modal, I am using two buttons in a View. But the problem is - no margin is working between them.

Here's the code

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Modal 
        animationType={"slide"} 
        transparent={false}
        visible={this.state.ModalVisibleStatus}
        onRequestClose={() => { console.log("Modal has been closed.") }}
    >
        {/*All views of Modal*/}
        {/*Animation can be slide, slide, none*/}
        <View style={styles.modal}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Modal is open!</Text>

            <View style={styles.inputContainerEmail}>
                <Image style={styles.inputIcon} source={{ uri: this.state.catImage }} />
                <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                    placeholder="Email Address"
                    keyboardType="email-address"
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text, 'email')} />
            </View>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Button style={{ marginRight: 10 }} title="Save" onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ ModalVisibleStatus: !this.state.ModalVisibleStatus })
                }} />

                <Button style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} title="Close" onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ ModalVisibleStatus: !this.state.ModalVisibleStatus })
                }} />
            </View>
        </View>
    </Modal>
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#DCDCDC',
    },
    modal: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#aaaa',
        padding: 100
    },
    text: {
        color: '#3f2949',
        marginTop: 10
    }
)}
```

After running these code it's getting following output-

[image]

So how can I add margin between these two buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React-Native `Button` is very limited in what you can do, and *doesn't support a style property as far* as I know.  I would suggest looking into using [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity) or [TouchableNativeFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback) to customize your needs.

A potentially dirtier solution would be to wrap both `Buttons` inside a separate individual parent `View` component and applying your `margin` property to these parent `View` components instead. Alternatively, you could perhaps specify `justifyContent:'space-between'` on your parent `View` Component as is and seeing if that gives the desired result too. For example, the multiple view approach might look something like the following:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex:1 , marginRight:10}} >
         <Button title="Save" onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ ModalVisibleStatus: !this.state.ModalVisibleStatus })
         }} />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:1}} >
        <Button title="Close" onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ ModalVisibleStatus: !this.state.ModalVisibleStatus })
        }} />
    </View>
</View>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for informing the limitation of Button. I solved it easily using TouchableOpacity.

Comment: And I tried the code you provided, it also works :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `justifyContent:"space-between"` in your button view code as

```
<View style={{ flex:1, flexDirection: 'row' , justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
                <Button style={{ flex:1}} title="Save" onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ ModalVisibleStatus: !this.state.ModalVisibleStatus })
                }} />

                <Button style={{ flex:2 }} title="Close" onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ ModalVisibleStatus: !this.state.ModalVisibleStatus })
                }} />
            </View>
```

Link for reference https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/